# Vertical WildMenu in Vim

Tags: autocompletion, wildmenu

One thing that really bothers me in vim (probably the only thing), is the wildmenu.

In **neovim**, the wildmenu is *vertical* and looks as following:

[image]

However, in **vim**, it is *horizontal* and looks like this:

[image]

**Is it possible to get the vertical wildmenu in vim?**

If possible, without a plugin, but if there is no other way then I don't mind.

Comment: The only one-entry-per-line command-line completion I'm aware of is for a very specific situation: when using `:tag` and you press Ctrl-D but only if you've done `:set wop=tagfile`. Yeah, extremely limited.

Comment: Kind of a shame since we know Vim can do that kind of display...autocomplete of any kind in the buffer does it. Sounds like a worthy feature request. (Assuming I'm not missing something already there.)  Welcome to Vi&Vim SE, BTW.

Comment: @BLayer  I have `set wildoptions="pum,tagfile"` enabled, but i still get the horizontal menu

Comment: `set wildoptions="pum"` this is a neovim only addition. I don't think vim currently allows to use a vertical popup menu for the wildmenu.

Comment: Actually, you've found a bit of a Vim issue. I believe the `:set` that you ran should emit an error message because it is rejecting the value...`:set wop?` shows no right-hand-side value. Now try it without the double quotes, `:set wop=pum,tagfile` and you'll get an error. But anyways...if you want to see the completion format I mentioned in my first comment you'll have to type it just like I show.

Comment: And is there an existing plugin that allows to get some sort of a vertical wildmenu?

Comment: I'd guess no because that seems like the kind of functionality beyond the reach of vimscript (IOW, it could only be done in the source code). But I don't know for sure. Did you check [VimAwesome](https://vimawesome.com) ?

Comment: Since the functionality is build in, you should change the accepted answer accordingly: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/34709/29189

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not available in Vim. However, there is a fork called [Vim-CLPUM](https://h-east.github.io/vim/). You need its `clpum` branch, which is 2 years behind Vim's `master` at the moment. If you really like this feature, maybe you could help **h-east** with testing it or in some other way.

Comment: for now, i will just keep using neovim ;) *sigh... I want to stay native to vim, but there a some little things like this that i can't stand about vim..

Comment: Wow...what are the odds that there's a branch (even a hopelessly outdated one) that does exactly what they want. How the heck did you know about it? I'm impressed. :)

Comment: @BLayer, I don't remember, probably saw the fork being mentioned in Vim's GitHub [issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/5432) or somewhere else accidentally.

Comment: Well, +1 regardless.

Answer (score 11):

[Patch 8.2.4325](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/3908ef5017a6b4425727013588f72cc7343199b9) added the vertical wildmenu support to Vim.

Comment: Which version of Vim? How do you enable it?

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly what OP asked but... maybe someone will find this useful.

There are countless plugins (commonly referred as "pickers") that allow user to pick an item from (vertical) popup menu and to execute some arbitrary command afterwards (vim-clap, nvim-telescope, you name it). Probably many of us also tried to create "fast buffer switch" or "colorscheme chooser" that works without even entering cmdline. Now with Vim8 `+popupwin` it's easy!

The main disappointment is that (callback) lambdas are really awkward to re-use: imagine we have a dozen of individual "pickers" each of which calls a generic `Pick()` function which in turn calls `popup_menu()`. Now every "picker" wants to have specific callback lambda but every lambda should also have access to all locals in `Pick()` too! Luckily, we can work around it using good old "substitute-eval-submatch" trick.

So the code for our generic `Pick()` function is

```
" Pick({name} [, {items} [, {cmd}]])
" pick parameter and execute {cmd}
function! Pick(...) abort
    let l:name = a:1
    let l:items = a:0 > 1 ? a:2 : getcompletion(l:name..' ', 'cmdline')
    let l:cmd = a:0 > 2 ? a:3 : '%{name} %{items[result - 1]}'
    call popup_menu(l:items, #{title: printf('[%s]', l:name), maxheight: &pumheight ?
        \ &pumheight : &lines / 2, minwidth: &pumwidth, callback: {id, result ->
        \ (result < 1 || result > len(items)) ? v:null :
        \ execute(substitute(l:cmd, '%{\([^}]\+\)}', '\=eval(submatch(1))', 'g'), '')}})
endfunction
```

So the third (optional) parameter is a String to evaluate and execute in the context of `Pick()`'s internal lambda. And inside our "special" `%{...}` expression we can actually access all those local variables! That allows for super-easy writing of menu callbacks.

```
" Choosing :colorscheme is trivial
nnoremap <silent><plug>colorscheme <cmd>call Pick('colorscheme')<CR>

" Choosing from :scriptnames using custom items and cmd
nnoremap <silent><plug>scriptnames <cmd>call Pick('scriptnames',
    \ map(split(execute('scriptnames'), "\n"), 'v:val[1:]'), '%{result}%{name}')<CR>

" Choosing buffer is a bit verbose as we have to prepare buffers list
nnoremap <silent><plug>buffers <cmd>call Pick('buffer', map(getbufinfo({'buflisted': 1}),
    \ {_, v -> printf('%2d %s', v.bufnr, empty(v.name) ? gettext('[No Name]') :
    \ fnamemodify(v.name, ':t'))}), '%{name} %{split(items[result - 1])[0]}')<CR>
```

And all others like "args", "find", "history", "marks", "oldfiles", "registers", "windows" and even "picker of pickers". The code is in my [vimfiles repo](https://github.com/matveyt/vimfiles/blob/fc2133a5d8fad9c58de510a739bd68c681f9ff0f/vimrc.d/40map.vim#L116). This gives us roughly a half of functionality of those plugin monsters such as nvim-telescope with only a few lines of "poor old" VimScript.

Comment: cool use of popups

Comment: Slightly more judicious use of continuation lines might make this easier to read.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Lambdas and mappings are always hard to fit properly in VimScript. I admit my technique is far from good.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Are there plans for a vertical wildmenu in Vim? I find all the options given not pleasing. The vertical menu is the only thing so far I find better in Neovim.

Comment: @neolith I am not aware of this. You may open a wishlist issue for this for Vim. Not sure this will make it implemented, since we have popup menus, so you might be prepared for some discussions about it

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I will file a feature request then. The horizontal menu ist just tedious to read

Comment: @neolith Vertical wildmenu in Nvim belongs to GUI shell exclusively (neovim-qt only?) So core Neovim team doesn't even have to do anything about that. On the other hand, adding this feature to vim would probably require multiple implementations for different platforms (at least win32, gtk and mac). So.. you can open an issue, but you definitely have more chance if you submit PR (preferably for all major platforms at once ;-)

Comment: The vertical wildmenu works in terminal Neovim for me as well. I am not sure what is needed to implement it, but Vim's wildmenu is not pretty. I am not good enough in Vim script yet, so I will file a request.

Comment: But I guess you could easily display the wildmenu in the drop-down menu that is already there

Comment: @neolith Ah, okay. Now I spend too little time in Neovim, so I got confused. It is actualy `:h 'wop'` extension in Neovim that allows using `:h popupmenu-completion` for wildmenu. Not the "Guipopmenu" I was talking about. So it could be more or less painlessly ported to Vim too, I guess. BTW. `:h popupmenu-completion` is also different from `:h popupwin` in Vim or `:h floatwin` in Neovim. So it's really easy to get confused with all these.

Comment: Yeah that is why I don't use Neovim. It is hard enough to learn Vimscript and in Neovim you have lua as well, which makes the init.vim quite confusing. Maybe I will switch to it in the future, but atm all of these differences are just confusing.

Comment: @neolith You don't have to learn or use Lua in order to run Neovim. Lua is only good for plugin writers. Ordinary users could/should just stay away from it.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for posting this question.
The same thing is bothering me as well.

At first, I thought there was a new plugin - [wilder](https://github.com/gelguy/wilder.nvim), but it appears (to me) that the vertical-nature is not given.

> I did not try to install the python dependencies.

Nonetheless, I am recommending to try the following pair of options:

```
set nowildmenu
set wildmode=list:full
```

This is the best aid and *almost* mimics the vertical menu when completing the cmdline.

---

update on 03. Juli 2022, because vim 9 was released.

The changelog did not prompt me with this feature, but the following thread: [How to get vertical wild menu using wildoptions=pum on Vim 9.0](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/37854/29189).

After a short search, the following PR (attribution!), even though it was not merged, initiated the support for this menu: https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/9707.

You need to activate an alternative behaviour by

```
set wildmenu
```

Then configure it like so:

```
set wildoptions=pum
```

Have fun!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!