# How to get vertical wild menu using wildoptions=pum on Vim 9?

Tags: wildmenu, vim9

I would like to test the new vertical wildmenu of Vim 9.

I read that `set wildoptions=pum` should provide it. But I'm not successful.

Is there another setting to set to get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `vim -Nu NONE`
2. `:set wildmenu wildoptions=pum`
3. `:e <tab>`

[image]

Comment: Hi Maxim, is there a way to get the same menu using the <C-d> completion?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I don't think so (as of today)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt You can use `:set wildchar=<C-d>` if you prefer to use `<C-d>` over `<Tab>`, although that will break Tab. Not sure how to have both; e.g. `cnoremap <C-d> <Tab>` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to:

1. enable wildmenu: `:set wildmenu`
2. set wildoptions to `pum`: `set wildoptions=pum`
3. trigger completion using <kbd>tab</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>