# Can I use Telescope to find all commands and functions?

Tags: neovim, functions, user-commands, plugin-telescope

I am switching over from Emacs, Doom Emacs specifically. It had a very nice feature where you could just press `M-x` and then start typing the command you're looking for and it will fuzzy find it for you. It also showed the key combination next to it though that's not as important to me.

I am trying to do the same with Telescope, but Neovim works a little differently. There are no "commands" per se, but functions that you can call. Is there a way I can search over all the functions available? e.g. if I want to call `vim.lsp.buf.hover()` or some other function like that.

I do sometimes use `:Telescope keymaps`. It does do what I'm asking for but only if a keymap exists for the function I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If you are searching for lsp symbols you can do:

```
:Telescope lsp_document_symbols
```

[image]

[image]

For this to work you need to have Neovim LSP framework to be connected to the corresponding LSP server.

In order to do that I recommend to install:

- [mason-lspconfig](https://github.com/williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim)

That require:

- [mason](https://github.com/williamboman/mason.nvim)
- [nvim-lspconfig](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig)

You can then install the LSP server for Python with the Neovim command: `:MasonInstall pyright`

Comment: Three answers to one question? I'm impressed. Vi stands for Vivian, doesn't it? :-)

Comment: I don't know Emacs and I'm not sure what the OP wants to achieve: code completion, command completion or searching symbol :-|

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to get a menu for Vim command you could do:

```
:set wildmenu
:set wildoptions=pum
```

[image]

Obtained by typing `:set wild`<kbd>tab</kbd>

see the following [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/37856/23502).

If you like it you may like even more the [wilder](https://github.com/gelguy/wilder.nvim) plugin.

Comment: I don't think this is what I was asking for. But thanks a lot

Comment: Are you searching for buffer functions or Vim commands?

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for code completion my recommendations would be to install a completion plugin like:

- [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim)
- [nvim-cmp](https://github.com/hrsh7th/nvim-cmp)

Under the assomption that you have already configured the associated connections to a language server.

For `coc` You can do it for Python using the command `:CocInstall coc-pyright`

For `nvim-cmp` I would recommend to install:

- [mason-lspconfig](https://github.com/williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim)

That require:

- [mason](https://github.com/williamboman/mason.nvim)
- [nvim-lspconfig](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig)

You can then install the LSP server for Python with the Neovim command: `:MasonInstall pyright`