# Can a popup_menu's callback access its popup_menu's first argument?

Tags: variables, popup-menu

For now I have the feeling the answer is *no*, but I'm asking to make sure that's the case, and to know if people has found workarounds or can suggest good approaches.

From [`:help popup_menu`](https://vimhelp.org/popup.txt.html#popup_menu%28%29) I've found this example

```
func ColorSelected(id, result)
   " use a:result
endfunc
call popup_menu(['red', 'green', 'blue'], #{
    \ callback: 'ColorSelected',
    \ })
```

and tried  it out, chainging the commented line to `echo a:result`, thus discovering that `a:result` is actually the 1-based index of the item into the list that is the first argument to `popup_menu`.

Indeed, at [`:help popup-callback`](https://vimhelp.org/popup.txt.html#popup-callback) I read that (my emphasis)

> The callback is invoked with two arguments: the ID of the popup window and **the
> result, which could be an index in the popup lines**, or whatever was passed as
> the second argument of `popup_close()`.

that seems to confirm my understanding.

So if I wanted the callback to `echo` back `red`/`green`/`blue`, what options would I have?

I'd be tempted to say that the only way to accomplish the task, without introducing code/data duplication, is to have a `g:`lobal variable that both the call to `popup_menu` and the definition of the callback share. Something like this:

```
let g:pumcolors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
func ColorSelected(id, result)
  echo 'choice made: ' .. a:result .. ' which is ' .. g:pumcolors[a:result - 1]
endfunc
call popup_menu(g:pumcolors, #{ callback: 'ColorSelected', })
```

So is this the only way? Or am I missing some obvious approach?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/34710/22797

Comment: @Matt, _Not exactly what OP asked_, indeed. I think that answer belongs to this question more than to that. I wonder if somebody can move that answer here, together with comments and votes. Because this question is not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 1):

Popup windows, like all windows in vim, have buffers that contain the text within them.  Thus, you can use `getbufline` to retrieve the text.

```
func ColorSelected(id, result)
  echo getbufline(winbufnr(a:id), a:result)
endfunc
call popup_menu(['red', 'green', 'blue'], #{
      \ callback: 'ColorSelected',
      \ })
```

Now, when the popup window is closed this buffer is removed.  However, in the context of this callback, it seems to remain valid.